# Reading unicode from messageSource gives problem with Java 5

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, internationalization, character-encoding

I made an Spring(2.5.6) webapplication with i18n support with property files (ex: messages_en_US.properties, messages_de_DE.properties).

This .properties files with uni-codes. for example:

```
busy = Besch\u00E4ftigt
```

When reading `busy` keyword from the `messageSource` gives this result:

```
...
private static ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    /**
     * Gets a message from the resources (.properties) defined in the applicationContext.xml
     *
     * @param input string to hook up
     * @return the the message hooked up from the resources
     */
    public static String getMessage(String input){
        System.out.println(input); //busy
        System.out.println(messageSource.getDefaultEncoding()); //UTF-8
        System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage(input, null, null)); //Beschu00E4ftigt
        return messageSource.getMessage(input, null, null);
    }
...
```

so without the  `\`

The files on the server are also UTF-8:

[image]

The environments where the problem occurred:

- Tomcat 5.5.28 (Run `jsp-api.jar` and `servlet-api.jar` from `common/lib` )
- JDK 1.5.0_22
- JSTL 1.1.2 (read from application `lib`)
- Tomcat 6.0.32 (Run `jsp-api.jar` and `servlet-api.jar` from `lib` )
- JDK 1.5.0_22
- JSTL 1.1.2 (read from application `lib`)

The environments where the problem is solved (exactly the same distribution):
 - Tomcat 6.0.32 (Run `jsp-api.jar` and `servlet-api.jar` from `lib` )
 - JDK 1.6.0_13
 - JSTL 1.1.2 (read from application `lib`)

Please let me know if you need more information. And don't say I need to update my JDK because this isn't possible.

**Update binding messageSource in applicationContext.xml**

```
<b:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <b:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <b:property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
    <b:property name="basenames">
        <b:list>
            <b:value>classpath:messages</b:value>
            <b:value>/public/custom/i18n/portalmessages</b:value>
        </b:list>
    </b:property>    
    <b:property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
</b:bean>
```

**Update 2: Place resource property file on classpath and with classloader:**

```
URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) IOUtils.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream resourceAsStream = cl.getResourceAsStream("messages_de_DE.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(resourceAsStream);
System.out.println("From classpath --> " + prop.get("busy")); //Beschäftigt
System.out.println("From i18n folder --> " + I18nFunctions.getMessage("busy")); //Beschu00E4ftigt
```

Comment: Can you post an excerpt from the `applicationContext.xml` that defines the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource` please?

Comment: @Harry Lime : See update on the post

Comment: Seems that the rule `this.propertiesPersister.load(props, new InputStreamReader(is, encoding));` from `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` encounters problems when encoding is "UTF-8". When I change the encoding back to `ISO-8859-1` the problem is solved. Now I only need to check in Chinese tokens works for example.

Comment: Unfortunatelythis improvement doesn't work in all cases so I made a CustomResourceBundleMessageSource without define an encoding and use `props.load(inputstream)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a look at the Source code of `DefaultPropertiesPersister` (it's used by `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` internally).

If a `defaultEncoding` is specified, the properties are loaded manually line-by-line from a `Reader` instead of using the conventional `Properties.load()` method.

Before adding the key/value pair to the `Properties` object, the `unescape()` method is invoked on the `String`s

```
protected String unescape(String str) {
    StringBuffer outBuffer = new StringBuffer(str.length());
    for (int index = 0; index < str.length();) {
        char c = str.charAt(index++);
        if (c == '\\') {
            c = str.charAt(index++);
            if (c == 't') {
                c = '\t';
            }
            else if (c == 'r') {
                c = '\r';
            }
            else if (c == 'n') {
                c = '\n';
            }
            else if (c == 'f') {
                c = '\f';
            }
        }
        outBuffer.append(c);
    }
    return outBuffer.toString();
}
```

This is where the `\` character is getting removed.

If you create a subclass of `DefaultPropertiesPersister` as follows

```
package com.something;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.springframework.util.DefaultPropertiesPersister;

public class MyPropertiesPersister extends DefaultPropertiesPersister {
    protected String unescape(String str)
    {
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);
    }    
}
```

Set it in your spring config like so:

```
<b:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <b:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <b:property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
    <b:property name="basenames">
        <b:list>
            <b:value>classpath:messages</b:value>
            <b:value>/public/custom/i18n/portalmessages</b:value>
        </b:list>
    </b:property>    
    <b:property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
    <b:property name="propertiesPersister">
        <b:bean class="com.something.MyPropertiesPersister"/>
    </b:property>
</b:bean>
```

It will work.. there may be further jiggery-pokery required to get exactly what you want in relation to other encodings, etc :)

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer. But for now I don't need the usage of the `DefaultPropertiesPersister`. so i simply replace it with `props.load(inputstream)`; This works like charm. even with Chinese or Russian chars and in JDK5 and JDK6. (lower than JDK5 isn't required)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
> ```

When called *before* any `getParameter()` call, this only instructs the servlet API what encoding to use to parse the parameters of the POST (not GET!) **request** body.

You still have to change the **response** encoding to use UTF-8 so that the servlet API knows what encoding it should use to emit the characters as bytes to the other end of the HTTP connection. You also still have to instruct the webbrowser by the HTTP response headers what encoding the transferred bytes are in so that the webbrowser can properly decode them to characters.

In JSPs, both tasks can be accomplished by this single simple line in top of the file. You need to apply this on *all* JSPs, also the include files/fragments.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Otherwise the server platform default encoding will be used for sending and client platform default encoding for the reading (although some smart webbrowsers like Firefox can autodetect the charset when it's been unspecified in the HTTP response header).

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

---

**Update**: are you sure that the unicode escapes aren't by itself re-escaped in the properties files in the Linux machine? I.e., you are seeing `\u00E` and like over all place and thus not `\\u00E`? That would explain the issue.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I wish this solved the problem. But the solution you mentioned was already implemented: <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><%response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");%><%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");%>

And I use a CharacterEncodingFilter. I use JSTL to display i18n messages... so: <fmt:message key="foo"/>.

Comment: Setting response encoding is already implicitly done by pageEncoding. Setting request encoding in JSP is pointless since it's usually too late already. Just the pageEncoding for the response encoding (and headers) and the filter for the request encoding is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. That makes sense. Unfortunately this does not solve the problem...

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. It was just a comment. Please note the answer update at the bottom as to solving the concrete problem.

Comment: "Please note the answer update at the bottom as to solving the concrete problem" ?? I don't understand what you mean with this comment.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Look at the bottom of my answer. There is a paragraph which starts with **Update**. Did you see/read it?

Comment: Ow haha sorry... :-) Yes when I read the .properties files on the filesytem I see: "changes = Einschr\u00E4nkung" and in the application I see "Einschru00E4nkung" . Do you mean this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you check the locale as the user running the server, or to be more exact, you need to check the locale of the environment the server starts in. For debugging purposes you might be able to edit the start scripts to write the output of “locale” to some file.

Comment: Sounds good, but Is there a possibility that you check this for other users when you logged in as administrator on the linux server ( I have only one SSH login)

Comment: Yes, you need to check it as the user that runs the server because that environment is the one that determines what the JVM uses as default encoding. The encoding the environment of your login user only matters if you run the server as this user.

Comment: So I understand that you can't check the Locale settings of an other user, for example the 'root' user? Maybe you know a page with more information about this? I'm a linux noob.

Comment: Right. As you are obviously not the person managing the server running your application, please contact somebody who is responsible for that and have them check the environment.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from javadoc for java.util.Properties,

> The load(InputStream) / store(OutputStream, String) methods work the same way as the load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, except the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes ; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape sequence. The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property files to and from other character encodings.

Perhaps you have some build phase that is converting your UTF-8 encoded file into ascii. Try to change the encoding of the properties files to 8859-1. Sounds like your properties file already escapes the Unicode characters appropriately.

Also use the `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)` to get a stream to the properties file yourself, and load into a Properties file. See if the values are the desired strings. This will 1/2 the problem to an encoding+packaging vs. a spring problem.

**Update based on comment thread:**

The [Java 1.5 java.util.Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) does *not* have a `load(Reader)` API. So clearly, this was an area of improvement in the Java 1.6 timeframe.

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga: I try to convert the files to 8859-1 again (default in Eclipse) but this doesn't solve the problem. I going to try the second suggestion later on.

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga: Your second suggestion gives a interesting result. see my update2. I think there is a problem with the Spring `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`? Or  I'm wrong?

Comment: I would crack open the implementation of said class, and see what it is doing.

Comment: I was already reading the source and use it ;) [source](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-context/2.5.6.SEC02/spring-context-2.5.6.SEC02-sources.jar!/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.java?format=ok). Seems that the `PropertiesPersister` does something wrong. On this line:
`this.propertiesPersister.load(props, new InputStreamReader(is, encoding));` after this props is wrong

Comment: Unfortunatelythis improvement doesn't work. I now made a CustomResourceBundleMessageSource without define an encoding and use simple `props.load(inputstream)`